# Automatically linking dynamic (swift) libraries via Cocoapods in Cordova project

Tags: swift, cordova, cocoapods, xcode8

I am including some Swift libraries via Cocoapods in my Cordova project. In order to get the project to archive I need to manually link them by clicking the plus button in General > Linked frameworks and libraries. This is fine, but I am trying to get this working automatically on a CI server where this intervention is not possible.

Is there a way to tell these pods to link automtically, either on a post_install hook or a Cordova build hook somewhere?

Comment: how are you adding the swift libraries?

Comment: I'm new to cordova and swift (taking over a project whereby the client needs to use a third party swift library). I have a cordova plugin which specifies a pod as a required framework in its plugin.xml. The plugin is installed in the after_platform_add hook, I then run pod install in the same hook in order to install the dependencies. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: When using Objective-C pods you don't have to manually link the frameworks, nor run pod install on a hook, that's why I was asking. I have not tried with Swift pods, can you tell me some of the pods you are using?

Comment: Were implementing a third party OAuth provider which have provided a Swift SDK, this in turn depends on CryptoSwift, JSONWebToken, JWTDecode and Locksmith. Ive also found that in order to run a release build I need to manually add these into the embedded binaries section under general.